# Android: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForFlavorDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi am facing the following error in Android Studio ..

```
 Error:Execution failed for task
 ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForFlavorDebug'.
  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
 com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class
```

Project was working fine but I dont know why it start giving this exception .. I did not changed anything in gradle file..

**gradle File:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Project'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('./../project/project.keystore')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 38
        versionName "2.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavor {
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
    }
    //    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
    //    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar')
    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.8.7.jar')
    compile project(':image-chooser-library')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.+@aar'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'javax.media:jmf:2.1.1e'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am using;

> Windows 8.1 pro,
>   Android Studio 2.3.3

What i Tried till now;

> 1. Clean Build Rebuild
> 2. gradlew clean
> 3. Delete Both build folders

Nothing worked

Can please someone help me .. if any other information required please let me know

**Updated Information:**
Working on emulators without changing anything but not on my handset even it was working on it aswell

Comment: @intelliJAniya you mean `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'` this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your app's `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
compile('com.google.zxing:core:2.1') {
                exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
            }
```

and remove this line:

```
compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are not using flavours then just remove the flavour section in gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Project'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('./../project/project.keystore')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 38
        versionName "2.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
  // comenting the flavour section 
  //  productFlavors {
  //     flavor {
  //      }
  // }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
    }
    //    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
    //    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar')
    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.8.7.jar')
    compile project(':image-chooser-library')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.+@aar'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'javax.media:jmf:2.1.1e'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```